# Regex: words containing alphabetic characters surrounded by non-alphabetic characters

Tags: regex

I'm a noob with regex and I need help solving this:

> Find and remove all ocurrences of groups of 1 or 2 alphabetic
>   characters, that are surrounded by non-alphabetic characters.
>   You may encounter latin characters that must be treated as any
>   alphabetic character. Using PHP, PCRE regex flavor.

For example:

**Remove:**
a
aa 33 a3 3a
aa3 a3a 3aa 33a a33 3a3
aa3a a3aa 33a3 3a33 aa33 33aa a3a3 3a3a 3aa3 a33a
aa3aa 3aa3a a3a3a aa3a3 33a33 a33a3 3a3a3 33a3a a3a33
aa3aa3 a3a3a3  3a3a3a 33a33a

and so on...

In cases like "aa3aaa", the regex would need to match the aa3 part.

This what I got so far:

```
(\b\d*?[a-z]{1,2}\d*?\b)|(\b(\d+?[a-z]{1,2}\d+?)+?\b)|(\b([a-z]{1,2}\d+?[a-z]{1,2})+?\b)|(\b(\d+?[a-z]{1,2})+?\b)|(\b([a-z]{1,2}\d+?)+?\b)
```

img: https://www.debuggex.com/i/gkZ0uhVVhoysmN81.png

[Regex at Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7gPEeHvOR3-Q7ga-)

I cannot match the words:
3l3l3
l3l3l

Also I cannot match partially the word:
aa3aaa

Any help improving my regex would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't match `3l3l3`/`l3l3l`, as they contain an alphabetic character surrounded by non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: `In cases like "aa3aaa", the regex would need to match the aa3 part.`...Those are 3, not 1 or 2 !

Comment: @lucas-trzesniewski, when I said that I couldn't match those words, what I meant to say is that I am not able to with the regex I made. Sorry, not a native speaker :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say which regex flavor you use, here's a way using PCRE:

```
(?<!\p{L})\p{L}{1,2}(?!\p{L})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK1qH6/1)

This translates your requirement in this way:

- groups of 1 or 2 alphabetic characters: `\p{L}{1,2}`
- not preceded by an alphabetic character: `(?<!\p{L})`
- not followed by an alphabetic character: `(?!\p{L})`

You can replace `\p{L}` with something like `[a-zA-Z]` if your flavor doesn't support Unicode properties.

Comment: Sorry, dont't know what flavors are in regex. I read about it and yes, this will work for me, as I'm using php. Thank you very much!